# How to join two tables without performing Cartesian product in SQL

Tags: sql, hive

I have index_date information for IDs and I want to extract baseline ( information between index_date and Index_date minus 6 months). I want to do this without using Cartesian product.

Total Table

```
ID index_date detail
1  01Jan2012  xyz
1  01Dec2011  pqr
1  01Nov2010  pqr
2  26Feb2013  abc
3  02Mar2013  abc
3  02Feb2013  ert
3  02Jan2013  tyu
4  07May2015  rts
```

I have a table A extracted from Total which has the index_dates:

```
ID index_date index_detail
1  01Jan2012  xyz
2  26Feb2013  abc
3  02Mar2013  abc
4  07May2015  rts
```

I want to extract baseline periods data for IDs in A from from the Total table 
Table want :

```
ID date index_date detail index_detail
1  01Jan2012 01Jan2012 xyz xyz
1  01Dec2011 01Jan2012 pqr xyz
2  26Feb2013 26Feb2013 abc abc
3  02Mar2013 02Mar2013 abc abc
3  02Feb2013 02Mar2013 ert abc
3  02Jan2013 02Mar2013 tyu abc
4  07May2015 07May2015 rts rts
```

code used :

```
create table want as 
select a.* , b.date,b.detail
    from table_a as a 
    right join 
    Total as b
on a.id = b.id where
 a.index_date > b.date 
    AND  b.date >= add_months( a.index_date, -6)
;
```

But this requires Cartesian Product. Is there a way to do this without requiring Cartesian product.

Comment: 1) Not `RIGHT JOIN` but `INNER JOIN`. 2) Joining conditions must be specified in ON clause. 3) No way to avoid a cartesian. In general. But if you specify the DBMS and its version, a solution can be found.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions . DBMS - Hive

Answer (score 0):

> DBMS - Hive

Sorry, I don't know it.

I'll give the solution on pure SQL for MySQL 8+ - maybe you'll find the way to convert it to Hive syntax.

```
SELECT id, 
       index_date date,
       FIRST_VALUE(index_date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(index_date, '%d%b%Y') DESC) index_date,
       detail,
       FIRST_VALUE(detail) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(index_date, '%d%b%Y') DESC) index_detail
FROM test
ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 DESC
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9e50aff7ee6420b4711314d3b536c55a)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend three steps:

1. Convert the date to a number.
2. Find the minimum date in a six month period.
3. Get the first value in that group.

This looks like:

```
select t.*, t2.index_date, t2.detail
from (select t.*,
             min(index_date) over (partition by id
                                   order by months
                                   range between 6 preceding and current row
                                  ) as sixmonth_date
      from (select t.*,
                   year(index_date) * 12 + month(index_date) as months
            from total t
           ) t
     ) t left join
     total t2
     on t2.id = t.id and t2.index_date = t.sixmonth_date;
```

This is marginally simpler if `first_value()` accepts `range` window frames -- but I'm not sure if it does.  It is worth trying, though:

```
select t.*,
       min(index_date) over (partition by id
                             order by months
                             range between 6 preceding and current row
                            ) as sixmonth_date,
       first_value(detail) over (partition by id
                                 order by months
                                 range between 6 preceding and current row
                                ) as sixmonth_value
      from (select t.*,
                   year(index_date) * 12 + month(index_date) as months
            from total t
           ) t
```